# Visa requirement for UK

Tags: visas, uk, thai-citizens, australian-residents

I am a permanent resident in Australia married to an Australian Citizen.
I am travelling to the UK to visit my husbands family but I have a Thailand Passport. Do I need a visa for UK for holiday entry?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if you need a visa here https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa Family members of UK citizens are not eligible for a Family Permit, so you will need a Standard Visitor visa to enter the UK.